# How do I calculate the point that is the least total distance from three other points?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm trying to find a way to calculate the point at which the total distance from other points is at a minimum. In other words I'm trying to find a way to find the point at which the function $$d(x,y,z)=\sqrt{(x-x_1)^2+(y-y_1)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_2)^2+(y-y_2)^2}+\sqrt{(x-x_3)^2+(y-y_3)^2}$$ is at an absolute minimum.
Does such a solution exist?

Comment: @DavidK . Also known as the Steiner point.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I hadn't heard that one. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerPoints.html

Comment: @DavidK . Steiner investigated the Q of connecting a finite number $n\ge 3$ of planar points with a path of minimal total length. This is called the Steiner Point Problem.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Got it. The Fermat Point occurs in the solution for the Steiner tree for $n=3.$ Nice generalization.

Comment: @DavidK . There is a variant called the Orthogonal Steiner Point Problem where the connecting line segments must be parallel to one or the other co-ordinate axes. I have heard this affects the layout of connections of components within an integrated circuit.